# android: Handle events of AlertDialog components in Parent Activity

Tags: android, events, android-listview, android-activity, android-alertdialog

In my app I have a scene where I need to show listView with title in many situations.

So I created a gen_list_layout.xml with a TextView & a ListView in it.

Now to show the list, I planned to create a method "public static AlertDialog createAlertDialog(String title, String[] items, Activity activity)" where I can create teh AlertDialog for the same.

```
    public AlertDialog createAlertDialog(Activity act, String title, String[] items) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater   = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gen_list_layout,null);

    TextView titleTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.genListTitTv);
    titleTv.setText(title);

    ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.genList, items);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.genList);
    listView.setAdapter(ad);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

     // I WANT THIS TO BE HNDLED IN THE ACTIVITY CALLING    
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,  long id) {              
        }

    });

    AlertDialog.Builder scrnDlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
    scrnDlg.setView(view);

    final AlertDialog adg = scrnDlg.create();

    return adg;
}
```

I will call the createAlertDialog(), from different Activity wherever I need the list.

```
  AlertDialog ad = Components.createAlertDialog(RouteListActivity.this, title, items);
```

Now how do I handle click events for the ListView that is in AlertDialog ??

Any clue, how to implement such.

**UPDATE**
I update my Q after implementing your approach & I see an exception. Can't get teh cause of the exception. I created a class and added createAlertDialog :

```
public class ListAlertDialog {

public AlertDialog createAlertDialog(Activity act, String title, String[] items, OnItemClickListener clickListener) {
    Log.i("ListAD", "Start to create Alert Dialog");
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater   = (LayoutInflater)act.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gen_list_layout, null);

    Log.i("ListAD", "Got View :" + view.getId());
    TextView titleTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.genListTitTv);
    titleTv.setText(title);
    Log.i("ListAD", "Set Title TV : " + titleTv.getId());

    ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(act, R.layout.list_item, R.id.genList, items);
    Log.i("ListAD", "Created Adapter");
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.genList);
    listView.setAdapter(ad);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    Log.i("ListAD", "Got ListView :" + listView.getId() + " & Set Adapter");

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(clickListener);
    Log.i("ListAD", "Added Listerner to listView : " + clickListener.getClass());

    AlertDialog.Builder scrnDlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
    scrnDlg.setView(view);
    Log.i("ListAD", "Set View of scrnDlg");

    final AlertDialog adg = scrnDlg.create();
    Log.i("ListAD", "Created Alert Dialog & returning it : " + adg );       
    return adg;
}
}
```

My gen_list.layout.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/genListTitTv" style="@style/inPageTitleStyle"             
        android:text="" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/genList" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" android:divider="@null" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In my Activity, I m calling as :

```
        ListAlertDialog lad = new ListAlertDialog();
    AlertDialog ad = lad.createAlertDialog(Mumbai77Activity.this, "Select", items, clickListener);
    Log.i(TAG, "Got the AD in Activity : " + ad + " ABT to Show");
    ad.show();
    Log.i(TAG, "Shown ad");
```

The error that I get in logs is NullPointerException :

```
08-30 12:52:00.247: I/ListAD(366): Start to create Alert Dialog
08-30 12:52:00.257: I/ListAD(366): Got View :-1
08-30 12:52:00.257: I/ListAD(366): Set Title TV : 2131230764
08-30 12:52:00.257: I/ListAD(366): Created Adapter
08-30 12:52:00.257: I/ListAD(366): Got ListView :2131230765 & Set Adapter
08-30 12:52:00.267: I/ListAD(366): Added Listerner to listView : class    org.mumbai77.core.Mumbai77Activity$2
08-30 12:52:00.267: I/ListAD(366): Set View of scrnDlg
08-30 12:52:00.267: I/ListAD(366): Created Alert Dialog & returning it : android.app.AlertDialog@44f29668
08-30 12:52:00.267: I/Mumbai77(366): Got the AD in Activity : android.app.AlertDialog@44f29668 ABT to Show
08-30 12:52:00.297: I/Mumbai77(366): Shown ad
08-30 12:52:00.417: D/AndroidRuntime(366): Shutting down VM
08-30 12:52:00.417: W/dalvikvm(366): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
08-30 12:52:00.437: E/AndroidRuntime(366): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-30 12:52:00.437: E/AndroidRuntime(366): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-30 12:52:00.437: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:353)
08-30 12:52:00.437: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
08-30 12:52:00.437: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
08-30 12:52:00.437: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1198)
08-30 12:52:00.437: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1109)
08-30 12:52:00.437: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
08-30 12:52:00.437: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
08-30 12:52:00.437: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
08-30 12:52:00.437: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
08-30 12:52:00.437: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
08-30 12:52:00.437: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
08-30 12:52:00.437: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
08-30 12:52:00.437: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-30 12:52:00.437: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
08-30 12:52:00.437: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
 ................
```

On looking at the exception, I can't get the actual problem, but on looking at the logs that I have added I can see that the Got View : -1
I beleive `View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gen_list_layout, null);`has some problems. It is not able to get the view or somethign like that.

Any idea what can be th problem with the View - why it is not getting the view of layout ? Any modifications to b done in the layout or the inflate() ?

Any help is highly appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass an `OnItemClickListener` as a parameter to your `createAlertDialog` method.

The creator method:

```
public AlertDialog createAlertDialog(Activity act, String title, String[] items, OnItemClickListener clickListener) {
LayoutInflater layoutInflater   = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gen_list_layout,null);

TextView titleTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.genListTitTv);
titleTv.setText(title);

ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.genList, items);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.genList);
listView.setAdapter(ad);
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

 // I WANT THIS TO BE HNDLED IN THE ACTIVITY CALLING    
listView.setOnItemClickListener(clickListener);

AlertDialog.Builder scrnDlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
scrnDlg.setView(view);

final AlertDialog adg = scrnDlg.create();

return adg;
}
```

Your activity:

```
OnItemClickListener clickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,  long id) {
         // Do some stuff in your activity's scope here. 
    }
}

AlertDialog ad = Components.createAlertDialog(RouteListActivity.this, title, items, clickListener);
```

Comment: how r u telling to implement? Different Activities & items will have different actions to be performed. How can I do this ?

Comment: Updated my answer with an example. Basically you create your listener in the scope of whatever activity you're calling from, then pass it to your create function to attach it to the list.